# SQL- insert row into table based on value, then determine position in table

Tags: sql

I have a website which records hours played of a certain videogame. The table currently holds the name and hours played of 20k players. If a new user enters their information, how could I determine their position in the table?

Ideally a method which is as easy as possible on the CPU so it can deal with bursts of traffic, and even if the table grows (I assume ORDER BY is not advised for very large table!?)

For example, current table:

User //  Hours played
Bob  //  54
Dave //  584
Steven // 63

New user is Andy, hours played 300. I simply want to get returned the value '2' as he is the second on the table, ordered by hours played descending.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question with your tables layout and also with some sample data and what you want returned.

Comment: Relational database tables don't have an inherit notion of "position" - unless you explicitly use an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` statement, there is **no order** in a relational table

Comment: I added sample data as requested.

Comment: As mentioned above you do not insert at a specific row. After insert you could e.g find the ranking of the player using the `rank`function in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax will vary depending on the database server you use (MySQL versus Oracle versus Microsoft SQL Server), but all modern RDBMS's support indexes in some fashion.  By constructing the appropriate index (and then tuning on appropriate hardware), an ORDER BY clause or windowing function is perfectly acceptable even on large tables.

Comment: I am VERY new to sql (and only looking into it for a hobby) and I know nothing about this? I assumed all programming languages are the same, even in different environments? Why is Microsoft and oracle different?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using the 'RANK' function:.

Here's a quick example of how it could work using Microsoft SQL Server:

```
--Create an example of your table
CREATE TABLE #HoursPlayed
(
    vchName VARCHAR(255),
intHoursPlayed INT
)

--Add in the initial daa
INSERT #HoursPlayed VALUES ('Bob', 54), ('Dave', 584), ('Steven', 63)

--Now add in Andy
INSERT #HoursPlayed VALUES ('Andy', 300)

--Now see where Andy fits in the list ordered by hours played
SELECT RANK()OVER(ORDER BY hp.intHoursPlayed desc) Position, *
FROM #HoursPlayed hp
```

Andy will be returned as position '2' from the SELECT statement as he has the second highest number of hours played in the list of players.

The above syntax can easily be altered to return a single row and the position of the player in the overall list.

To appease the user questioning the solution, here's the final query that you can use. It will allow you to specify a single user and get there position in terms of hours played

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT RANK()OVER(ORDER BY intHoursPlayed desc) Position, *
   FROM #HoursPlayed
) hp
WHERE hp.vchName = 'Andy'
```

Note that using a subquery can be detrimental on large datasets.

Comment: Although I have written something similar I really think this is a textbook example of bad practice and it shouldn't be encouraged, especially not with simple problems like this one.

Comment: I disagree as it's the initial solution for the problem. Looking at your solution/suggestion, a primary key does not solve the request (even though it looks like the table could do with one). If you continued and then added in the row for 'Andy', it will return an ID value of 4. This is not what the user wants. They want to return the position of the row (i.e. the player) based on the ordering of hours played descending.

Comment: Well, if you run the query SELECT RANK()OVER(ORDER BY hp.intHoursPlayed desc) Position, *
FROM #HoursPlayed hp
where vchName='Andy' you will see how your logic fails. RANK works well if you pull the whole data. If you limit your selection to one record (and that is what the initial problem was) you get the wrong result and thus buggy software. So I will say it again: this is bad practice.

Comment: My final comment clearly says that the syntax can easily be altered to return a single row and position of the player in the overall list, i.e. exactly what you just questioned. I was giving an example of how the function worked.

Comment: You are working on the whole dataset. You really dont see how this is bad?

Comment: Which I've already put in my comment so the user is aware of the potential effects. I'm not here to argue your invalid points. If you have another solution, feel free to post one. Otherwise, end of conversation...

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1) + 1 as Place
from Players
where HoursPlayed > (select HoursPlayed from Players where UserName = @UserName)
```

Answer (score -3):

if I understood you right, you have a simple table like this:

```
Table(USRNAME, HOURS_PLAYED)
```

..and information in that table is as such:

```
"Bob", 54
"Dave", 584
"Steven", 63
```

There is basically nothing wrong with this layout but if you want to retrieve the "position" from the database, you really should add another column with an unique value. This kind of columns are called [primary keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp).
Why should you use this? Because relational databases work best if you treat them like bags of marbles. You tell the database which data you want and the database engine finds it for you. They are based on [set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model). So your new table should look something like this:

```
Table(ID, USRNAME, HOURS_PLAYED)
1, "Bob", 54
2, "Dave", 584
3, "Steven", 63
```

This would be the "correct" way of doing it or as it is usually phrased: the best-practice.

THAT SAID, there is a way, but I strongly advise against using it. MS SQL and also other database engines incoroporate a concept of ROW_NUMBER(). When you `SELECT` data from table, the server retrieves it in a 2D table. SQL engine is able to calculate the **index (not necessarily the actual position in the table!!!)** if the returned row. Please refer to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx.

So imagine a query like this:

```
SELECT USRNAME, HOURS_PLAYED FROM Table WHERE USRNAME='Bob';
```

This query would return the correct record, but you dont know the position.
If you use an ID column, it would be simple.

```
SELECT ID, USRNAME, HOURS_PLAYED FROM Table WHERE USRNAME='Bob';
```

This query would return number 1.

But please keep in mind that database engine **doesn't care** the position of the record. So there is no difference between ID=3 and ID=23454 for the database itself. Just a number without a semantic meaning.

I suggest you read up on the database design basics and you will be able to solve the rest of your db-related problems fairly quickly.